# lit-html: how to render contents of .innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, sitecore, innerhtml

I'm creating a custom component library and using it inc onjuction with a react component library framework called Sitecore jss. I have the following:

`<custom-component><Text/></custom-component>`

In this instance `<Text/>` renders as

```
<span>
   <span>Stuff</span>
</span>
```

What I'd like to have happen in that the span inside of my custom component gets rendered as html. However, using `.innerHtml` gives me a string of the html rather than actual html. Is there a way to get lit-html to render innerHtml as html and not as a string?

Comment: `<input>Stuff</input>` --- invalid

Comment: It's just for the sake of the example. But thanks for pointing that out. I'll delete it.

Comment: I guess ```<xmp></xmp>``` might help you.
Please find the below-working demo: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-list-element-ghsiyy?file=testElement.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I can use the `<slot>` element instead of `.innerHtml` in my component.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but it should work with innerHTML also, with the one thing to note that it's `innerHTML` (all letters uppercase in HTML). So in Polymer context you would use it as `inner-h-t-m-l` and in LitElement as `.innerHTML="${somethingHere}"`. I am using that approach for content that comes from a CMS, where I have the HTML as a variable and I can't use a slot.